# Confused about what V8 actually is

Tags: javascript, v8

I know V8 is a JavaScript engine, but is it also a runtime environment? I know a runtime environment supplies the engine with the event loop, APIs, callback queue etc, but from things I've read it seems that V8 supplies them as well? Is it engine > runtime environment or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V8 is a JavaScript engine that provides a runtime environment.

The JavaScript runtime environment, provided by V8 or any other JavaScript Engine consists of the memory heap, and call stack, where the actual JS code is being compiled and executed.

The event loop, Web APIs and the callback queue are not provided/supplied by V8, rather they are provided by the environment that V8 is hosted in. The hosting environment for V8 can be the browser (like Google Chrome) or Node.js.

If you look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kF43.png), on the left side inside the border line, lies the JS runtine environment provided by V8. On the right side, you can see Web APIs, Callback Queue and the Event Loop provided by the browser (the hosting environment). Hope it clarifies.

Image credits: sessionstack [blogpost](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5).

For further details and clarification, you can have a [read](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/getting-started/the-v8-javascript-engine) about the V8 JS Engine. Plus, this video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) is really helpful and exactly addresses your question.

Comment: Is the browser not the runtime environment?

Comment: No, the browser is a hosting environment. Inside the browser, there lies V8, Web APIs, Callback Queue and the Event Loop. And V8 is what provides the runtime environment. So you can say that the runtime environment (provided by V8) is wrapped by the hosting environment (the browser).

Answer (score 0):

No. V8 compiles and executes JavaScript source code, handles memory allocation for objects, and garbage collects objects it no longer needs. V8’s stop-the-world, generational, accurate garbage collector is one of the keys to V8’s performance.

JavaScript is commonly used for client-side scripting in a browser, being used to manipulate Document Object Model (DOM) objects for example. The DOM is not, however, typically provided by the JavaScript engine but instead by a browser. The same is true of V8 — Google Chrome provides the DOM. V8 does however provide all the data types, operators, objects and functions specified in the ECMA standard.

V8 enables any C++ application to expose its own objects and functions to JavaScript code. It’s up to you to decide on the objects and functions you would like to expose to JavaScript.

Comment: the answer above says it supplies a runtime environment?